# Python loop to Comprehensive list

Tags: python

I'm new to Python Programming, this is my code;

```py
myList = " Bob said, breakthrough study reveals that human and octopus brains have common features"

for word in myList.split():
    if word[0] == "b":
        print(word)
```

Can I simplify this code above to a list comprehension in Python?

Can't find the solution.

Comment: You should not really use a list comprehension with side-effects; printing in your case. Leave the code as it is.

Comment: `print([i for i in my_list.split() if i.startswith("b")])`

Answer (score 0):

**Your existing approach seems OK to me** but not sure if you want something like this or not with [list comprehension](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/list-comprehension). **Note**: your `mylist` name has a typo.

```
mylist = " Bob said, breakthrough study reveals that human and octopus brains have common features"
word = [word for word in mylist.split() if word[0] == "b"]
print(*word)
```

Comment: I'm new to Python programming, so this solution helps me to understand the way to write a comprehensive list in Python. Thank you.

Comment: @Cassiopea glad it helps you somehow, btw: don't forget to check on green tick of my answer :)